# what does this symbol mean? ⊂((・x・))⊃

Tags: symbols

⊂((・x・))⊃

I see it in chat in some multiplayer games from Japanese players

Comment: looks like a koala.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an emoji, not Japanese language.

Comment: @istraci Isn't an emoji a non-textual character like  whereas an emoticon is the use of characters in an artistic way like :)?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm HiruneDiver's answer below explains the difference between emoji (like ``) and kaomoji (like `:)`).

Comment: Yes, pardon me but I didn't know even it is called a kaomoji. You can close the question, but the accepted answer is very valuable. Where can I ask this type of questions?

Comment: @Sanandrea see [this meta post](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/kaomoji-on-topic) regarding this question and Kaomoji identification requests.

Comment: @Sanandrea On this site, the community decides what sorts of questions are on-topic by voting.  It takes 5 votes to close a question, but so far only 2 close votes have been cast, while 3 people have voted to leave it open.  And in the [meta discussion](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/kaomoji-on-topic) about whether these sorts of questions are on-topic, several users supported an answer saying they should be allowed.  So although there's some disagreement, at the moment it looks like your question is considered on-topic and will remain open :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about the Japanese language

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The kaomoji ⊂((・x・))⊃ doesn't have a fixed universal meaning. It always depends on a preference of a person who uses it and the situation where the kaomoji is used.

There are at least three possibilities.

First, ⊂((・x・))⊃ may represent a rabbit. Especially, [Miffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miffy) in some cases. ⊂ and ⊃ are her/his ears or arms. 
A simple kamoji (・x・) has been thought Miffy for years. So people who are familiar with (・x・) tend to think ⊂((・x・))⊃ a variation of the Miffy face kaomoji (・x・).

Second, ⊂((・x・))⊃ might represent a monkey face. ⊂ and ⊃ are her/his ears. But in many cases, a monkey face is expressed by using some other kaomoji like this.

> ⊂((・⊥・))⊃

Third, ⊂((・x・))⊃ may represent a human or a personificated animal (rabbit in most cases) who is flying. ⊂ and ⊃ are her/his arms. The onomatopoeia for this kaomoji is usually ぶーん or ブーン.

> ぶーん⊂((・x・))⊃

Sometimes s/he is actually flying, and sometimes s/he is pretending to be flying with her/his arms since s/he is not a bird and can't fly actually. The kaomoji with this meaning is used when someone comes or goes to somewhere. For example,

> ちょっと行ってくる⊂((・x・))⊃

indicates that the speaker is going by flying or feeling flying.

Some people use ⊂((・x・))⊃ to express that they are bored or have nothing to do. S/he is flying because s/he has nothing else to do in this case.

In any case, the point is that the kaomoji ⊂((・x・))⊃ is a face which doesn't show any obvious emotion. So, it could express any kind of emotions which a speaker has. So if you really want to understand what the speaker means using ⊂((・x・))⊃, you should understand the context correctly.

By the way, Japanese symbols, such as ⊂((・x・))⊃ etc., are called kaomoji in Japanese.

Emoji ([絵文字]{え・も・じ}) is something like these.

[image]

Kaomoji ([顔文字]{かお・も・じ}) is something like these.

U・x・U   dog or rabbit

@(・●・)@   koala

＠ 'ェ' ＠   sheep

ϵ( 'Θ' )϶   fugu

( ´ ▽ ` )ﾉ   human raising her/his left hand

The default Japanese keyboards on iOS contain all of these kaomoji above, including

⊂((・x・))⊃.

So it's easy for people who have iPhone or iPad to use them these days. (Sorry, I don't know anything about android default keyboards.) You might see these kinds of kaomoji more in chat of mobile app.

Comment: Flying plus koala? Maybe it's a dropbear!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm haha( ´ ▽ ` ) it could be. Most native Japanese speakers don't know what a dropbear is, though.

Comment: @HiruneDiver yes, I wondered how the japanese team players wrote this kaomoji so fast. So if it already in the iOS keyboard now it explains everything. And I was wondering why it appeared on almost all messages. Thank you!

Comment: なんという的確な回答((((；ﾟДﾟ)))))))！ミッフィーであってると思います！androidでもiOSでも日本語のキーボードなら簡単に顔文字が出せるんですよ！

Answer (score 1):

No special meanings, just a character like Miffy spreading its arms!

Answer (score 0):

It's a monkey emoji. There's a few pages online that explain it, this is one: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1084135540